# Shortcode Ultimate Wordpress Adding Image to tab

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to put unique icons onto a custom tabs created using shortcode ultimate, but nothing seems to be working. It may be something obvious that I'm missing. I made three custom css classes that I've attached to each tab. In the css, each class has a unique icon image. Nothing appears in the tab (I don't want any text in the tab, just an icon).

My shortcode:

```
    [su_tabs]
      [su_tab class="my-custom-tab-1" title=""]
         some content
      [/su_tab]
      [su_tab class="my-custom-tab-2" title=""]
         some content
      [/su_tab]
      [su_tab class="my-custom-tab-3" title=""]
         some content
      [/su_tab]
     [/su_tabs]
```

My CSS:

```
     .su-tabs.my-custom-tab-1 div.su-tabs-nav .su-tabs-current { background-image: url('http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_53881/wp-content/themes/theme53881/images/icon1.png') }
     .su-tabs.my-custom-tab-2 div.su-tabs-nav .su-tabs-current { background-image: url('http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_53881/wp-content/themes/theme53881/images/icon2.png') }
     .su-tabs.my-custom-tab-3 div.su-tabs-nav .su-tabs-current { background-image: url('http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_53881/wp-content/themes/theme53881/images/icon3.png') }
     .su-tabs.my-custom-tab-4 div.su-tabs-nav .su-tabs-current { background-image: url('http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_53881/wp-content/themes/theme53881/images/icon4.png') }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a background to the tabs, then use selectors like this -

```
.su-tabs-nav .my-custom-tab-1 {
  background: url(..your url..);
}

.su-tabs-nav .my-custom-tab-2 {
      background: url(..your url..);
    }

.su-tabs-nav .my-custom-tab-3 {
      background: url(..your url..);
    }
```

Comment: I replaced my css with the code above and entered in the url for the image, but it still didn't work.

Comment: nevermind, I found what I did wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. Right now it only shows the background on the tabs that are not activated - how can I include the background image on the tabs that are activated?

Comment: In that case you use `.su-tabs-nav .my-custom-tab-1.su-tabs-current`
Notice there is no space between the last 2 class names.
And where did you go wrong?

Comment: Sorry for phrasing that awkwardly, but how do I have the icon showing in both the active and inactive tabs? Adding `su-tabs-current` makes it so that only the activated tabs show the icon. Also, my problem was just a dumb syntax error on my part after adding your css code

Comment: For all the tabs, use this `.su-tabs-nav span`

Comment: What is the correct syntax for that line of code? Right now I have `.su-tabs-nav span.my-custom-tab-1{`

Comment: I see what you mean by using `span`, but I'm not sure how to use span while still being able to have a unique image for each tab